# Convert JavaScript function to

Tags: javascript, java, function

I need to change this code from JavaScript to Java from this website:

https://jsfiddle.net/3L6L2fmv/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3L6L2fmv

This is the call from another function that generates random numbers but has a 1 in 51 chance of the number being zero: (where "hash" is a 64-bit hexadecimal number)

```
// In 1 of 51 games the game crashes instantly.
if (divisible(hash, 51))
    return 0;
```

And this is the function: (where mod is always 51)

```
function divisible(hash, mod) {
// So ABCDEFGHIJ should be chunked like  AB CDEF GHIJ
var val = 0;

var o = hash.length % 4;
for (var i = o > 0 ? o - 4 : 0; i < hash.length; i += 4) {
    val = ((val << 16) + parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;
}

return val === 0;
}
```

So basically when ever the JavaScript version returns a zero for a certain hash, I need the Java version to also return a zero for the exact same hash.

Here is my first attempt and pretty much as far as I can get due to my poor knowledge of JavaScript.

```
    public static double divisible(String hash, int mod) 
{
    int val = 0;        
    int o = hash.length() % 4;      
    int i = 0;

    if(o > 0) {i = o - 4;}
    if(o < 0) {i = 0;}

    for ( int a = i; a < hash.length(); a += 4) 
    {           
       val = ((val << 16) + Integer.parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;            
    }
    return val;
 }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I showed my attempt as far as possible. and am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just confused the variables a bit in your Java code, other than that, it seems fine.

```
public static double divisible(String hash, int mod) 
{
    int val = 0;        
    int o = hash.length() % 4;      
    int i = 0;

    if(o > 0) {i = o - 4;}
    if(o < 0) {i = 0;}

    for ( int a = i; a < hash.length(); a += 4) 
    {           
       val = ((val << 16) + Integer.parseInt(hash.substring(a, a+4), 16)) % mod;            
    }
    return val;
 }
```

The values in the substring should be **a** not **i**. 
You probably assumed i = index.

An improvement would be the following. You do not need to create a new variable in Java for loops.

```
public static double divisible(String hash, int mod) 
{
    int val = 0;        
    int o = hash.length() % 4;      
    int i = 0;

    if(o > 0) {i = o - 4;}
    if(o < 0) {i = 0;}

    for (; i < hash.length(); i += 4) 
    {           
       val = ((val << 16) + Integer.parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;            
    }
    return val;
 }
```

Comment: أحسنت يا سمير .. تعجبني

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI thank you, and yes it is just like the wind :)

Comment: Thank you so much! been struggling for hours. Really appreciate the help and for taking the time to go through my poor code.

Comment: @Joey no problem at all!